# How can I enable login and register pages in shopify

Tags: shopify, shopify-template

I have installed fresh shopify store but there is not way to purchase product in that fresh store.

Can any help me for this.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below step to enable login and register pages

1. Login to shopify admin
2. https://prnt.sc/wdpkrz

Answer (score 0):

You should follow these steps for enable login and register page on your store

1. login your store
2. Go to Your store admin panel.
3. After go to setting => checkout
4. After select "Accounts are required" this option and click on SAVE button